# How to configure aggregate device

Tags: audio

I'm looking for a way to create an aggregated audio device with a specific configuration, but not sure how to map them.

I've got a headset, iRig, garage band and other app.

Essentially I want to create this setup:

```
iRid input -> garage band -> mix -> headset output
                   |          ^
                   v          |
headset mic  ->   mix  -> other app
```

I expected I could map this to basically 2 aggregate audio devices with one of them:

"Mix for app":

- add headset mic as device's input - possible
- set garageband output to this - possible
- set app's input - not possible :(

I believe I could do this with the [blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) app, but it requires quite a bit of work to get more than 1 blackhole working at a time.

Apart from spending money on Loopback, what are my options here? Am I missing some possible configurations?

Comment: Have you experimented with the macOS native `Audio MIDI Setup` app?

Comment: Yes, as described, the aggregate audio device can't be used as an input in the app (zoom in this case)

Comment: OK. You didn't mention you'd tried Audio MIDI Setup. Perhaps you should edit your question for increased specificity. Perhaps [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) might help?

Comment: You can use aggregate for multiple I/o but not for inter-app comms. For that you’ll need BlackHole (which I’ve never tried) or Rogue Amoeba’s Loopback.